# how to toggle particular field with same id or class?

Tags: html, jquery

The 'comment' field has 'id' and 'class', I can't give a unique 'id' because it is coming from a database (dynamic output). I have tried to 'toggle' (hide and show) with Jquery, but when I click a particular 'comment' field all of the form (textarea) is appearing (Toggling). How do I toggle a particular field with same id or class?

```
$(".commentForm").hide();
    $(".askForComment").click(function(){
    $(".commentForm").toggle();
});
<div id='comments'>
   <div id='askForComment' class='askForComment'>Comments?</div>
   <div id='viewComments'></div>
   <form id='commentForm' class='commentForm'>
        <textarea cols='20' rows='2'></textarea>
        <input type='button'>
   </form>
</div><!-- this element is looped (dynamic) -->
```

[image: picture where i click]

[image: picture where the form toggle]

Comment: Even if the data is coming from a DB, the ID's still must be unique or else this wont pass validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should target the specific `.commentForm` here :

```
 $(".askForComment").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".commentForm").toggle();
 });
```

This will toggle the `.commentForm` which is near the `askForComment`. Or, you could do this :

```
 $(".askForComment").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".commentForm").toggle();
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$(".askForComment").click(function(){
    $(".commentForm").toggle();
});
```

To this:

```
$("#comments").on('click', ".askForComment", function(){
    $(this).next(".commentForm").toggle();
});
```

You don't want to use `.siblings()` because that gets ALL the matching siblings. You want to use `.next()` because it will only get the closest one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(".askForComment").on("click",function(){
    $(this).next(".commentForm").toggle();
 });
```

As it is the best option rather than `click` if your HTML formed at runtime means after `DOM` loding prefer to use `$(".askForComment").on("click",function(){`